# mongodb mongoose many to many with additional attributes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, many-to-many

I have two collections: (schema with mongoose)

[image: Collection Schemas]

In my app there can exist videos and some videos can be part of an event.
The point is I want to get all videos for a specific event, where the visibility (`event.videos.visibility`) is true, the video state is e.g. 1 and it should be sorted e.g. by `video.date_created` and `limit`/`skip`

**How do I have to change the collection schemas, to get the maximum performance?**

Is it a good idea to save important fields (like `date_created`, `state`) from the video also in the event (redundant information)?

Or is the actual schema a good solution?

The actual solution has 2 options for query:

First:
get the videos_visible - Array from an event and search videos, where id is in this array AND the events-Array in videos matches ($elemMatch) the event_id + visibility === true

Second: First solution without the array from the event

In both I can sort the videos and skip/limit them without problems..
but I don´t know if it is a good solution.

Another solution i tried was keeping the additional events/videos information like visibility or display_type in the event.videos_visible and not in the video itself.
The problem was, that i couldn´t sort the videos, or limit/skip them.
With mongoose-population it was not possible to skip/limit the video data dependent on e.g. the video.date_created. And in my opinion this isn´t the right way to handle this query/problem.

I think the problem is to model the right schema for this "many to many" case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it depends on the Number of Videos there can be for an event.

The question you should ask yourself is, **what's the cardinality?** Is the Event to Video relation a **One to Many or a One to few**.

**If it is a one to few**, then there's no problem embedding parts of Video like visibility and created_date, as it won't affect the size of the document as a whole so much. A plus point here would be that you'll be able to query the data much faster than if you did without embedding the videos and just referencing a video by video's _id field.

But if you want to update a video, then:

1. Either enter only those fields in the embedded Video document, that aren't going to change.
2. If you include the fields that might change in the future, then along with editing video in the video collection, you'll also have to edit it in each event in the event collection where that video exist as a sub-document.

**But if it is a one to many** relationship, then it's always advisable to use _id referencing in the event collection. Advantages of using this would be:

1. It will make sure that your document always stays less than 16MB.
2. If you have to update a video, then you'll have to do it only once in the Video collection.

but then the queries would be much time consuming.

I suggest you read this blog post once before making a choice.

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1

Comment: ok, its a 1-to-many cardinality, so saving the additional data in videos would be the better solution.. but is it better to search with the array from the event or without ? For example if there are 700 videos in an event, I do a query like "find streams where id in array and events: {$elemMatch: { event_id: event_id, display_type:2}}" or "find streams where {$elemMatch: { event_id: event_id, display_type:2}}" so without the array. Which one would be the better one? ps thanks for your fast response

Comment: Okay. So if its a one to many, just make sure that the many part is not way too large. Coz if it, then the size of your event document might grow and exceed the MongoDB Document size which is 16MB. So make sure that it isn't a ONE TO SQUILLIONS(as they call it). Also if you're embedding some parts of your video documents in your Events collection, I don't think you'll have to find videos from videos collection based on EventID. As you already have parts of those videos in your Event Document. So in all the design of your schema purely depends on your application's data access patterns.